# exec and shell_exec not working in php

Tags: php, shell, permissions, exec, shell-exec

I am having problems with exec and shell_exec i have looked at every post on here and cant seem to find the problem. the code i am using :

```
chdir('/');
$handle = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /home/donor/public_html/batch/testlaunch.php 2>&1");
echo $handle .":". gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
echo $read;
```

the screen looks like this:

```
...
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html (repeated about 100 times)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html 
PHP Warning: shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Unable to execute '/usr/bin/php /home/donor/public_html/batch/testlaunch.php 2>&1' in /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.php on line 4 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html 
Warning: shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Unable to execute '/usr/bin/php /home/donor/public_html/batch/testlaunch.php 2>&1' in /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.php on line 4
:boolean PHP Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.php on line 6 
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.php on line 6
:string PHP Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.php on line 6 (repeated another 100ish times)
```

PHP safemode is turned off. Permissions for the folder the files is in .../batch/ and the /usr/bin/php are both set to 755. The user for all files are the same except for php (php file user is root). Nothing is disabled in the php.ini file. Works fine in the CLI. and simple commands such as `whoami` and `ls` work fine. I feel like i am missing something

EDIT:
tried what cpattersonv1 said and got:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html 2540000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

EDIT 2: does anyone know why it looks like it is trying the command more then once?

EDIT 3: I put the command inside a .sh file and tried to run that. works in CLI but again does not work from php

```
chdir('/');
$handle = exec(". /home/donor/public_html/batch/test.sh");
```

I get the same output;

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump($handle)

Comment: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html string(641) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21 Content-type: text/html string(573)

Answer (score 2):

Try passthru intead, that way there aren't any limits on the execution if it takes a while:

```
<?php

 passthru("/usr/bin/php /home/donor/public_html/batch/testlaunch.php 2>&1",$pass_result);
 echo $pass_result; 

?>
```

or this:

```
<?php

 passthru("/usr/bin/php /home/donor/public_html/batch/testlaunch.php",$pass_result,$error);
 echo $pass_result; 
 echo $error; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your webserver user to a group with rw permissions to the batch directory. Either as root or using sudo:

```
usermod -G groupname username
```

then on the batch directory:

```
chmod -R g+w batch
```

Comment: you will not need to use chmod because your permissions are already 755

Comment: if i give it write permissions it gives me a internal server error when i visit the page and the batch folder is already donor donor which is the webuser

Comment: reading your post again, I noticed your shell_exec is pointing to /usr/bin/php and you reference /bin/php in your description. Use 'which php' to know the location of php on your server

Comment: i am sorry i was just shortening it it should be /usr/bin/php thats what all the php procesess say on the server 'process manger'

Comment: is there possibly another directory that i need to give permissions too?

Comment: who did you run it as in the cli?

Comment: i ran it in the shell as donor

Answer (score 0):

apparently i was using the wrong php file/path >< like a dummy thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post, here is my answer for other users.

1. Change the directory to the executable path
2. Call shell_exec() without the path of the executable
3. Revert the directory back to the original (so that some other part of code is not hampered).

Example

```
$current_dir = getcwd();
$executable_dir = "\executables\";
chdir($executable_dir);

$output1 = shell_exec("executable.exe file_to_run.ext $parameter_to_pass");
var_dump($output1);

chdir($current_dir);
```

Comment: A note for those "other users": pay attention to that `\"` at the end of the second line: that is an escape of the double quotes and will give you an error. Replace the `\` with `/` (on Linux), or even better use the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, this way: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "executables" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`